# Prove that given collection of subset is a topology.

Tags: general-topology

**Problem**

Let $X$ be a set ; let $\tau_c$ be the collection of all subsets $U$ of $X$ such that $X-U$ either is countable or is all of $X$. Prove that $\tau_c$ is a topology on $X$.

**Attempt**

1) $X,\phi \in \tau_c $

2) for any set $ {U_\alpha} \subset \tau_c $ where $I$ is the indexed set,
$X- \bigcup \limits_{\alpha \in I} U_\alpha $ = $ \bigcap \limits_{\alpha \in I } X- U_\alpha$. If for all $\alpha \in I ,U_\alpha=\phi$ ,we are done. If there are at least one $U_\alpha \neq \phi$, say $U_o$.Then $X-U_o$ is countable. Then 
$ \bigcap \limits_{\alpha \in I } X- U_\alpha \subset X-U_o$

3) similarly for intersection.

**Doubt**

Why $X-U_o$ is considered countable?

What if X is some uncountable set.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated .

Comment: Note that **$U \in \tau_{\mathrm c}$: $X - U$ is either countable or equals $X$**. If $U_o \neq \varnothing$, then ……?

Comment: I am sorry. I don't get it. I know if at least one of the $X-U_i$ is countable ,then we are done. But i am getting why $X-U_i$ is necessarily countable for any i.

Comment: Oh. I get it now

Comment: $X-U_i$ is either countable or all of X. So it follows.......thanks for the hint.

Comment: Feel free to check a similar post: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1837814/514490

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to help.